# Contents of table bigger than the rest of the text and also not centered

Tags: tables

I wrote the following code for inserting a table. But there are two problems:

- Contents are bigger than the rest of the text, even after using `\scriptsize` within a 12-point document
- Contents seem to be flushed left, but I want them to be centered

An MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.50in, right=1.00in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \caption{Table showing mapping  of sequences }
        \label{Table_CE1}
        \centering{
            \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
                \scriptsize  \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
                    \toprule
                    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{Original}\\   {Symbol}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{Mapped Symbol}\\ {with different}\\ Real /Imaginary Axis\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}{Mapped Symbol}\\ {with different}\\ Real and Imaginary axis\end{tabular}\\ \midrule
                    a & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Equal real parts (c or f)\\Equal imaginary parts (f or e )\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} c or e\\ d or f \end{tabular}\\\\
                    b & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Equal real parts (d or e)\\Equal imaginary parts (d or c )\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} d or f \\c or e  \end{tabular}\\
                    \bottomrule

            \end{tabular}}
        }
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're resizing to `\textwidth` a table that's smaller than it, so it is magnified.

Answer (score 4):

The tabular at natural size is narrower than the text width, so when you do the resizing the font size will grow bigger notwithstanding how small you set it to.

Just think to

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\tiny A}
```

which will make a very large ‘A’, even if it is declared `\tiny`.

1. Never apply `\resizebox` to a table.
2. Use natural size whenever possible.
3. `\centering` is not a command taking an argument.

Here's a fixed version, where I used `\makecell` for convenience over nesting `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.50in, right=1.00in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Table showing mapping  of sequences }
\label{Table_CE1}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
\makecell[l]{Original \\ Symbol} &
  \makecell[l]{Mapped Symbol\\ with different\\ Real /Imaginary Axis} &
  \makecell[l]{Mapped Symbol\\ with different\\ Real and Imaginary axis}\\
\midrule
$a$ & \makecell[l]{Equal real parts ($c$ or $f$)\\Equal imaginary parts ($f$ or $e$)} &
  \makecell[l]{$c$ or $e$\\ $d$ or $f$}\\
\addlinespace
b & \makecell[l]{Equal real parts ($d$ or $e$)\\Equal imaginary parts ($d$ or $c$)} &
  \makecell[l]{$d$ or $f$ \\$c$ or $e$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to get centering in the columns, you can remove `[l]`:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
\makecell{Original \\ Symbol} &
  \makecell{Mapped Symbol\\ with different\\ Real /Imaginary Axis} &
  \makecell{Mapped Symbol\\ with different\\ Real and Imaginary axis}\\
\midrule
$a$ & \makecell{Equal real parts ($c$ or $f$)\\Equal imaginary parts ($f$ or $e$)} &
  \makecell{$c$ or $e$\\ $d$ or $f$}\\
\addlinespace
$b$ & \makecell{Equal real parts ($d$ or $e$)\\Equal imaginary parts ($d$ or $c$)} &
  \makecell{$d$ or $f$ \\$c$ or $e$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Finally, if you want the table to fill the text width, use `tabular*`:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{}}
\toprule
\makecell{Original \\ Symbol} &
  \makecell{Mapped Symbol\\ with different\\ Real /Imaginary Axis} &
  \makecell{Mapped Symbol\\ with different\\ Real and Imaginary axis}\\
\midrule
$a$ & \makecell{Equal real parts ($c$ or $f$)\\Equal imaginary parts ($f$ or $e$)} &
  \makecell{$c$ or $e$\\ $d$ or $f$}\\
\addlinespace
$b$ & \makecell{Equal real parts ($d$ or $e$)\\Equal imaginary parts ($d$ or $c$)} &
  \makecell{$d$ or $f$ \\$c$ or $e$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how to center the table contents horizontally

Comment: @Ehsa Remove the `[l]` in the `\makecell` commands

Answer (score 3):

The answer from egreg addresses the scaling problem due to `\resizebox`.

The alignment problem is due to that you use `l` as argument in all your tabulars. Also, it is very hard to see what is going on when you use nested tabulars. Below I have first a version, where I have replaced all the argument `l` with `c` to get center alignment in the tables.

Then I have a second alternative using a version of `p{width}` which is centered. This is defined using the `array` package. To get the `a` and `b` symbols vertically centered I use the `multirow` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.50in, right=1.00in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \caption{Table showing mapping  of sequences }
  \label{Table_CE1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Original}\\   {Symbol}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Mapped Symbol}\\ {with different}\\ Real /Imaginary Axis\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Mapped Symbol}\\ {with different}\\ Real and Imaginary axis\end{tabular}\\ \midrule
    a & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Equal real parts (c or f)\\Equal imaginary parts (f or e )\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} c or e\\ d or f \end{tabular}\\\\
    b & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Equal real parts (d or e)\\Equal imaginary parts (d or c )\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} d or f \\c or e  \end{tabular}\\
    \bottomrule  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \caption{Alternative table showing mapping  of sequences }
  \label{Table_CE2}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}P{20mm}P{56mm}P{55mm}@{}}
    \toprule
    Original Symbol & 
    Mapped Symbol with different Real /Imaginary Axis &
    Mapped Symbol with different Real and Imaginary axis \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{a} & Equal real parts (c or f) & c or e \\
    & Equal imaginary parts (f or e ) & d or f \\[5mm]
    \multirow{2}{*}{b} & Equal real parts (d or e) &  d or f \\
    & Equal imaginary parts (d or c ) & c or e \\
    \bottomrule  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is use of `tabularx` for table environment (with it the table can span over text width and so exploit all available horizontal space), `multirow` for cells in the first column. With `makecell` is formatted the first column header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.50in, right=1.00in, 
            top=1.25in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table showing mapping  of sequences }
\label{Table_CE1}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cCC}%@{}
    \toprule
\makecell[t]{Original \\ Symbol}  
    &   Mapped Symbol with different Real /Imaginary Axis  
        &   Mapped Symbol  with different  Real and Imaginary axis    \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}*{$a$}
    &   Equal real parts ($c$ or $f$)
        &   $c$ or $e$                      \\
    &   Equal imaginary parts ($f$ or $e$)
        &   $d$ or $f$                      \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}*{$b$} 
    &   Equal real parts ($d$ or $e$)
        &   $d$ or $f$                      \\
    &   Equal imaginary parts ($d$ or $c$)  
        &   $c$ or $e$                      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]